# iisnode not starting node process

Tags: node.js, iis-8.5, iisnode

I have a very simple nodejs https server that I'm trying to get working with `iisnode`, but it doesn't appear that the node process is starting, so I get a 500 error when I try to navigate to it.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const fs = require('fs');
const cors = require('cors');
var https = require('https');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!')
});

var secureServer = https.createServer({
  key: fs.readFileSync('private.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('certificate.pem')
}, app).listen(process.env.PORT || 3443, function () {
    console.log('Secure Server listening on port 3443');
});
```

This application starts fine if I do node server.js, but when I try to rely on the node virtual directory that was set up by the `setupsamples.bat` script, it doesn't seem to work.  My Web.config also looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>
    <modules>
      <remove name="MyAuthModule" />
    </modules>
    <security>
      <authorization>
        <add accessType="Allow" users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </security>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="mcServer">
          <match url="mcServer/*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

`MyAuthModule` is a custom authentication module that was set up for me in my environment, so if I don't have that remove statement, I get an error about the module not existing.

I placed `server.js`, the Web.config displayed above, and the certificate files into its own `mcServer` directory in `iisnode/www` directory that was created by running the setupsample.bat script.  When I navigate to `https://myUrl/node/mcServer`, I get a 500 error, but if I navigate to `https://myUrl/node`, it displays the different apps that are available, and like I said, the node process is not running, so I think that's part of the 500 error that I get.

It's also good to note that I installed the url rewrite module, so that shouldn't be the issue, and `helloworld/readme.htm`, but once again, I'm assuming this is because node hasn't started.

I must be doing something totally stupid, but I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

There were several things that I had wrong:

- I was trying to use `npm link <module_name>`, but that apparently doesn't work with IIS, so I did `npm install` for all of the modules that I needed
- My `match url` should be `/*`, not `mcServer/*`
- In my server.js file, I need to prepend app.get with `app.get('/mcServer/'`